# Where do I find the Galaxy Tab specific Camera API documentation?

Tags: android

I want to see if it's possible to interfere with the "pre-flash" (the flickering the flash does prior to actually FLASHing with the photo), on the Tab.  The default camera app doesn't offer such a feature, and I wouldn't be surprised if there was no way to disable that functionality, but I'd like to see the API just in case it is possible. Does anyone know where/if Samsung (or Google) publishes its Tab specific API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the pre-flash thing you're talking about is the red-eye functionality. I may be wrong on this, but since the camera works with Android, you might want to try looking at the Android Camera API.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html

Search: FLASH_MODE_RED_EYE